# Ошибка при добавлении локальных файлов в репозиторий github-а

Tags: git, github

На гитхабе создал репозиторий и на него попытался залить локальные файлы.
При вводе в GitBush

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/WVFFLIFE/barbershop.git
```

выдает следующую ошибку:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
remote: Permission to WVFFLIFE/barbershop.git denied to Genavese.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/WVFFLIFE/barbershop.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Что делать с этой бедой?

Comment: Дайте осмысленный заголовок вопросу и опишите что Вы делали, когда получаете ошибку.

Comment: Похоже, что `remote` c именем `origin` уже задан. Возможно даже правильный. Попробуйте просто сделать коммит и пуш

Comment: `fatal: unable to access` точно появляется в ответ на команду `git remote add`? Может все-таки `git push` или `git pull`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Решение найдено:*
Необходимо зайти в:
Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей и семейная безопасность\Диспетчер учетных данных
в разделе: "общие учетные данные" удалить учётку для git. Выглядит она так:   `git:https://github.com`
При следующем взаимодействии в консоле, git попросит ввести логин и пароль в отдельном окне авторизации